# Git - List all files currently under source control?

Tags: git, source-control

Is there a way to list all files currently under source control in git? (Not just those that have been modified).

Answer (score 221, accepted):

If you want to list all files for a specific branch, e.g. `master`:

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only
```

The `-r` option will let it recurse into subdirectories and print each file currently under version control. You can also specify `HEAD` instead of `master` to get the list for any other branch you might be in.

If you want to get a list of all files that ever existed, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/543426/435093):

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A  | sort -u
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was looking for this.  Note that `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` would do the same as the first option, without needing the `cut`.  Ah, and you can specify `HEAD` instead of `master` if you just want this list for whatever branch you are currently on.

Comment: Running "git ls-files" will save you a few characters :)

Comment: Why was cut given the ending `-`?  It causes some additional lines to show some files in a second column which are repeats from the first.

Comment: @Adrian No idea, copypasted back then, fixed now.

Comment: Replace `master` with `$(git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2)` for current branch.

Comment: @ZainR more importantly, it gives you `-z` `--eol` and other nice options

Answer (score 98):

The `git ls-files` command will do what you need.

Source: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html

Comment: `git ls-files` instead of `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` is certainly simpler.

Comment: Sorry but my edit wasn't invalid. In current git there is no `git-ls-files` binary. There is the `git` binary with the `ls-files` command. The link to the documentation is correct in content, but technically for an outdated binary.

Comment: @JonnyJD, probably marked invalid because your edit should be a comment.

Comment: @JonnyJD All Git man-pages are named as `git-commit`, `git-init`, `git-ls-files`, etc. even though the programs are actually subcommands. There never was a `git-ls-files` binary, most likely. The reasoning is that it's consistent with the external subcommand mechanism, which allows you to register a `git foo` command by writing a `git-foo` binary.

Comment: This is indeed simpler, but on the other hand `git ls-tree` lets you specify a "tree-ish" (i.e. a branch, tag or commit), whereas `git ls-files` doesn't offer that option and works therefore only on `HEAD`.

Answer (score 7):

`git ls-files` will only print files in the current working directory.

If, for instance, you have a git repo for dotfiles (`core.worktree = /`), then you will have files outside the git root and that simple command won't work anymore.

In short, this will work:

```bash
git --git-dir "`git rev-parse --git-dir`" \
    -C "`git config core.worktree || pwd`" \
    ls-files
```

Example:

```bash
mkdir ~/dotfiles
cd ~/dotfiles
git config core.worktree /

# Ignore all files by default, else Git will find all files under "/"
echo "*" > .git/info/exclude

# Add files at the git repo's root and somewhere in the work tree
touch README
git add -f README
git add -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# `git status` would now print:
# new file:   ../../../etc/ssh/sshd_config
# new file:   README
git status

git commit -m "Initial commit"

# At this point, `git ls-files` prints only:
# README
git ls-files

# But you can print all files inside the work tree. This will print:
# etc/ssh/sshd_config
# home/yourusername/dotfiles/README
git --git-dir "`git rev-parse --git-dir`" -C "`git config core.worktree || pwd`" ls-files
```

If you want paths specified *relative* to your current (shell) directory, this does the job:

```bash
alias gls='git ls-tree -r master --name-only HEAD "`git config core.worktree`"'
```

and in the example above, it would print

```bash
README
../../../etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: In git v2.21, `git ls-files` shows all in the current directory and below. It just doesn't show files that were deleted in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `gitk` interactive repository viewer.

Comment: This mentions a tool, but doesn't really answer the "how".  Can you expand this into an actionable solution?  Just pointing someone in a research direction for them to develop their own solution is more appropriate as a comment.  Thanks.  [from review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/737832)

Answer (score -1):

[image: Screenshot]

Please have a look at the image, on right side there are two options patch and Tree.
If you select tree, you can view the folder structure for each commit.

Comment: Please consider a better commit to screen shot so you do not have to censor as much.

Comment: While I get the image could have been better, this IS actually a useful answer, and the users first (only!) answer.  I'd never realised that `gitk` has this tucked away in its UI.